How to make a POST request from a Chrome Extension with ORIGIN localhost
The Ollama API (a service for using LLM models locally) only accepts POST requests that originate from localhost. As you know. all the code for these extensions runs from chrome-extension://id.
Is there an elegant solution to make this POST request to the API so that its ORIGIN is localhost (127)?
*Both the extension and the Ollama server run on the same machine.
It seems these colleagues manage to do it, but I can't figure out how:
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/ollama-ui/cmgdpmlhgjhoadnonobjeekmfcehffco
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/page-assist-a-web-ui-for/jfgfiigpkhlkbnfnbobbkinehhfdhndo
The regular POST:
/ Function to send a POST request to the Ollama
async function postRequest(data) {
  const URL = `${ollama_host}/api/generate`;

  try {
      const response = await fetch(URL, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
          const errorData = await response.json(); // Or response.text() if not JSON
          document.getElementById('chatlog').innerHTML += `API returned an error: ${errorData.message}`;
      }

      return response; // Assuming the API returns JSON
  } catch (error) {
    document.getElementById('chatlog').innerHTML += 'Failed to post request: '+ error;
      throw error; // Rethrow or handle as needed
  }
}

UPDATE
It looks like this code would do the trick (for some reason it doesn't work on Edge side panels but it's ok for Chrome):
if (typeof chrome !== "undefined" && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.id) {
    rebuildRules = async function (domain) {
    const domains = [domain];
    /** @type {chrome.declarativeNetRequest.Rule[]} */
    const rules = [{
      id: 1,
      condition: {
        requestDomains: domains
      },
      action: {
        type: 'modifyHeaders',
        requestHeaders: [{
          header: 'origin',
          operation: 'set',
          value: `http://${domain}`,
        }],
      },
    }];
    await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
      removeRuleIds: rules.map(r => r.id),
      addRules: rules,
    });
  }
}


//set domain ORIGIN to localhost
if (typeof chrome !== "undefined" && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.id) {
  rebuildRules('localhost');
} 

